# Using hibernate UPDATE column of type "datetime" for mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, datetime, orm

I am using Hibernate for ORM mapping. One of the tables has a column of type "datetime". The column in question needs to be updated with "current-time" (time of data insertion). I am aware that I can use the date() function as the default value. I would rather prefer setting the timestamp when I set other attributes of the object.

Question
1) What is the equivalent of SQL date() function in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of SQL `date()` in java is simply `new Date()`, e.g.:

```
myEntity.setDateField(new Date());
```

will set `dateField` to the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql you can set an on update change : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The attribut will be updated with the current timestamp of the DB.

(you are lucky because it doesn't work with oracle ... (and I am with oracle ...) )

Comment: Thanks. This will work for me. But if the time stamp is other than "current" time stamp?

Comment: You're welcome
If the date is different, you'll have to set the date in your entity, and map your column with hibernate. (like any other field)

Answer (score -1):

I am trying in my code:

myEntity.setdDateCreated(new Date());

In hibernate mapping ->

property name="dateCreated" column="date_created" type="timestamp"

But in mysql it is saving as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Any guess why this is happening?